# Use If statement / conditional to output data to one file or another file C++

Tags: c++, file, if-statement, file-io, conditional-statements

New to C++. I have a #define variable (global variable? Not sure what these are called in C++) which I can set to a 1 or a 0. If it is == 1, I want my code to output my data to "File_A.txt". If it == 0, I want my code to output the data to "File_B.txt".

I tried to use an if statement when initializing the output file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
#define value 1
...
if (value == 1){
  ofstream fout("File_A.txt");
} else if (value == 0){
  ofstream fout("File_B.txt");
       }
```

but it seems like doing this makes the code not recognize `fout` as the output file identifier when I try to close the file `fout << endl;` and rather it thinks that `fout` is an undeclared variable... When I try to compile, it returns the classic error `error: ‘fout’ was not declared in this scope`.

I feel like this should be pretty simple, haha. Let me know if I need to supply more specifics. I tried to keep this brief and straight to the point.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. it's pretty simple. Are you aware that you can simply declare `std::ofstream` without opening any file, and then simply `open()` when you decide what you wish to open, later?

Comment: BTW, the `fout` variable will disappear after execution leaves the `if` statements.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That must be why it is giving that error. Thank you for the useful information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I was not aware of this. I thought the `open()` was used just for reading file input. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code fragment, based on Sam Varshavchik's comment:

```
std::ofstream fout; // Don't assign to a file yet.
//...
char const * p_filename = nullptr;
switch (value)
{
    case 0:  p_filename = "File_B.txt"; break;   
    case 1:  p_filename = "File_A.txt"; break;   
}
fout.open(p_filename);
```

In the above example, the filename is determined first, based on `value`, then the file stream variable is opened using the filename.

**Edit 1: Alternative**
An alternative is to determine the filename first, then declare the file stream:

```
char const * p_filename = nullptr;
switch (value)
{
    case 0:  p_filename = "File_B.txt"; break;   
    case 1:  p_filename = "File_A.txt"; break;   
}
std::ofstream fout(p_filename);
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you for your help and providing the layout of how to do this. I likely would not have figured out how to implement this if I was just going off of Sam's comment, so I am glad you added to it. I appreciate you.

Comment: I recommend adding `if (p_filename)` around opening the stream. Or throw exception or something like that.